# How to get child form's element?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

```
  form: ControlGroup
  childForm1: ControlGroup
  childForm2: ControlGroup
  childForm3: ControlGroup

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      name: [''],
      childForm1: fb.group({
        child1: [''],
        child2: ['']
      }),
      childForm2: fb.group({
        child3: [''],
        child4: ['']
      }),
      childForm3: fb.group({
        child5: [''],
        child6: ['']
      })
    });
  }
```

I can get `name` by two ways:

```
  console.log(this.form.find('name'));
  console.log(this.form.controls['name']);
```

But I cannot use similar way to get `child1`.

I know a way:

```
for (name in this.childForm1.controls) {
    if (name === "child1") {
        console.log(this.childForm1.controls[name]);
    }
}
```

But this still uses `childForm1` in the code.

Is it possible using only `form` and `child1` to get it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized this is nested objects problem. So I created a simplified question, and got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560396/how-to-get-child-objects-element#35560617) from @dave.

But in this case you cannot use `typeof` to decide whether is is `Control` or `ControlGroup`, I got [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562134/how-to-know-whether-it-is-control-or-controlgroup-in-angular-2/35562155#35562155) from @thierry-templier. So you need change a little bit of the code.

So he final working version:

```
getControl(controlName:string, controls:Object): AbstractControl {
    for (let i in controls) {
        if (controls.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if (i === controlName) {
                return controls[i];
            } else if (controls[i] instanceof ControlGroup) {
                let control:AbstractControl = this.getControl(controlName, controls[i].controls);
                if (typeof(control) !== "undefined") {
                    return control;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it

```
let control = this.getControl(this.controlName, this.form.controls);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to get the child controls of `child1`:

```
var child1Controls = this.form.controls.childForm1.controls;
```

As a matter of fact, the `group` method returns a `ControlGroup` element:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/ControlGroup-class.html

Comment: Thanks, but this still uses `childForm1` in the code. Is it possible using only `form` and `child1` to get it?

Comment: thanks! I got help from you for another question, ha. And the final working way, I posted here.