# How to get child object's element?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

How to get `e`'s value without knowing which group, which means only use `obj` and `e`?

And also can use same way to get `a`.

Thanks

```
let obj:Object = {
  a: 'value1',
  b: 'value2',
  group1: {
    c: 'value3',
    d: 'value4'
  },
  group2: {
    e: 'value5',
    f: 'value6'
  }
};
```

Comment: Besides flattening out the object, there really is no way to accomplish what you're asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
function findValue(key, obj) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if (i === key) {
                return obj[i];
            } else if (typeof(obj[i]) == "object") {
                var value = findValue(key, obj[i]);
                if (typeof(value) !== "undefined") { return value; }
            }
        }
    }
}

findValue('a', obj);
//"value1"
findValue('e', obj);
//"value5"
```

Comment: Nice use of recursion there.

Comment: amazing!! it works even in group's group's group, etc. thank you so much!

Comment: you may have a problem with falsey values.

Comment: @NinaScholz good call, fixed

Answer (score 2):

You can use Object.keys() to iterate through properties and Object.hasOwnProperty() to test if object contains property:

```
let key = Object.keys(obj)
                .find(k => obj[k].hasOwnProperty('e'));

console.log(obj[key].e);
```

Comment: thanks! is there a universal way? because now I cannot find `a`, `console.log(obj[key].a);`

Comment: This isn't flexible for other levels of nesting.

Comment: @HongboMiao this works only for 1 nested level as you originally asked. dave's answer works good also for nested objects

Comment: @madox2 yeah, I got it, still thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Version which returns falsy values, too.

```js
function find(key, object) {
    var value;
    Object.keys(object).some(function (k) {
        if (key === k) {
            value = object[k];
            return true;
        }
        if (typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            value = find(key, object[k]);
            return value !== undefined;
        }
    });
    return value;
}

var obj = { a: 'value1', b: 'value2', group1: { c: 'value3', d: 'value4' }, group2: { e: 'value5', f: 'value6' }, group3: { g: '', h: 0 } };

document.write(find('e', obj) + '<br>');
document.write(find('g', obj) + '<br>');
document.write(find('h', obj) + '<br>');
```

Comment: thanks, @NinaScholz!