# How to know whether it is Control or ControlGroup in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-forms

```
let aa = this._formBuilder.control("");
let bb = this._formBuilder.group({
    aa: aa
};
```

I want to do something like this:

```
if (typeof(aa) == "Control") {
    // do something
} else if (typeof(aa) == "ControlGroup") {
    // do something
}
```

But right now both `typeof(aa)` and `typeof(bb)` returns **object**.

```
console.log(typeof(aa));  // object
console.log(typeof(bb));  // object
```

How to know whether it is Control or ControlGroup? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if (aa instanceof Control) {
  // do something
} else if (aa instanceof ControlGroup) {
  // do something
}
```